# javafx UI glitching when any upd

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any changes to the list create a visual glitch (see gif sample below.) If I navigate away to another screen, then go back, it displays correctly again.

What can I do to fix this?

This is my controller:

```
public class BrowseCoursesController implements Initializable {
  @FXML private ListView<Course>  courseListView;
  @FXML private Label lblWelcome;
  @FXML private Button btnAddCourse, btnMyCourses, btnStudents;
  @FXML private TextField txtSearch;

  private App context;

  public void setContext(App context) {
    this.context = context;
    lblWelcome.setText("Logged in as, " + context.getActiveUser().getUsername() + "; Welcome.");

    // available courses
    ObservableList<Course> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      context.getCourseManager().getCourses()
    );

    // search feature, display all by default
    FilteredList<Course> filteredItems = new FilteredList<>(items, s -> true);
    txtSearch.textProperty().addListener(observable -> {
      String searchTerm = txtSearch.getText();
      if (searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
        filteredItems.setPredicate(s -> true);
      }
      else {
        filteredItems.setPredicate(s -> s.getCode().contains(searchTerm));
      }
    });

    courseListView.setItems(filteredItems);
    courseListView.setCellFactory(new CourseCellItemFactory());

    // set button visibility based on who is logged in
    btnAddCourse.setVisible(isAdmin());
    btnMyCourses.setVisible(!isAdmin());
    btnStudents.setVisible(isAdmin());
    // make buttons not take up UI space in their invisible state
    btnAddCourse.managedProperty().bind(btnAddCourse.visibleProperty());
    btnMyCourses.managedProperty().bind(btnMyCourses.visibleProperty());
    btnStudents.managedProperty().bind(btnStudents.visibleProperty());
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

  }

  public void onAddCourseButtonClick() {
    context.navigateToEditCourse();
  }

  public void onMyCoursesButtonClick() {
    context.navigateToMyCourses();
  }

  public void onRegisteredStudentsButtonClick() {
    context.navigateToAdminControlPanel();
  }

  private boolean isAdmin() {
    return context.getActiveUser() instanceof Admin;
  }

  // inner class for cell factory
  class CourseCellItemFactory implements Callback<ListView<Course>, ListCell<Course>> {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Course> call(ListView<Course> param) {
      return new CourseCellController(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but this is how I handle navigation in my main App class:

```
  public Initializable setScene(String page) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(page));
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(page);

    Parent node;

    try {
      node = (Parent) loader.load(in);
    }
    finally {
      in.close();
    }
    root.setCenter(node);

    return (Initializable) loader.getController();
  }
```

in the above, root is a border pane

```
private BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show `CourseCellController`?

Comment: Absolutely, here it is (along with the rest of the code) https://github.com/haosmark/CourseManagementSystem/blob/master/src/application/controllers/CourseCellController.java

Comment: Please note that questions should be self-contained (i.e. a [mre] should be in the question itself). That being said, try calling `setGraphic(null)` when the cell is empty or the item is null (currently you only call `setText(null)`, though I don't see you set it to a non-null value anywhere).